# How to install ls command in redhat linux

Tags: rhel

Can someone tell me how to install the `ls` command in RedHat Linux?

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 6):

the `ls` command is shipped by `coreutils` (`yum install coreutils`).

It is very unlikely this package would be missing (ships `mkdir`, `md5sum`, `pwd`, `sleep`, `tty`, ...)

Comment: Probably worth saying that `yum provides '*/ls'` will show name of package